# Convert an input file into a list of each line

Tags: python, list, file, input

I am approached with a problem of organizing an input file into a dictionary and for my algorithm I have decided to firstly turn an input file into a list of each lines (str). Basically, given:

```
ABCDE
FGHIJ ABCDEFG
FGHIJ ABCDEFG LOLOA
```

It will turn into

```
[['ABCDE'], ['FGHIJ', 'ABCDEFG'], ['FGHIJ', 'ABCDEFG', 'LOLOA']]
```

I am unsure how I can start.

Comment: you could start by reading the file. You couldnt even do that?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do two things:

1. Read in the file.  This is best accomplished with a [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).
2. Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or similar device to split the lines on whitespace.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> with open('/path/to/file.txt') as myfile:
...     print [line.split() for line in myfile]
...
[['ABCDE'], ['FGHIJ', 'ABCDEFG'], ['FGHIJ', 'ABCDEFG', 'LOLOA']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = "*.txt"

f = open(fname,'r')

lines = f.readlines()
```

open means to open the file, and 'r' option means to read it (other option includes 'w' to write)

Comment: Not really correct since readlines returns a list of strings and not a list of list of strings.

Comment: @RobParker right.. my fault, need to use split to separate the line